# C# print a pdf and overlap of process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printing, merge

When I print files A.pdf and B.pdf, I run this code:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\A.pdf") == true && File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\B.pdf") == true)
        {
            using (PdfDocument one = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\A.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
            using (PdfDocument two = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\B.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
            using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())

            {
                CopyPages(one, outPdf);
                CopyPages(two, outPdf);

                outPdf.Save(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\C.pdf");
            }
        }
```

but the program shows me an error:

```
"System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the 'C: \ Users \ Luca \ Desktop \ B.pdf' file because it is in use by another process.'.
```

I try to use the method `Task.Delay(500);` to allow time to print, but the error shows again

Comment: According to my test, I didn't meet the error you get. However, I have two suggestions. First, please check if your pdf file has been used by other app. Second, you can place your pdf path to d drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes when opening file failed before and the file stream still open, not been closed.
When I encountered a similar error, rebooting my PC to close all apps solved this error.

P.S.
The following code never stops your program.

```
Task.Delay(500);
```

We have to wait for a task to be completed.

```
Task.Delay(500).Wait();
```